# How to disable saved cards/future payment sheets of Stripe? (Android/Flask)

Tags: java, android, stripe-payments

I have an Android app that uses Stripe's SDK for purchases and a Gunicorn/Flask backend running. Testing has been well.

However, I do not want to store anything payment information. Yet, there is a checkbox option on the payment sheet to "*Save for future [app] purchases?*"

I've checked the client and server side documentation. But still can't figure out how to disable that option from the payment sheet. Does anyone know how? I'm writing in Java.

Comment: Please share your code. Likely you are creating a PaymentIntent that includes the parameter [setup_for_future_usage](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-setup_future_usage). If you remove that parameter, then that checkbox option won't show

Comment: That parameter was not in either my Android or Flask code. But I added it to the Flask payment intent as "off_session" and it is gone. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

In the Flask app set setup_future_usage to 'off_session'

```
paymentIntent = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
    amount=credits,
    currency='usd',
    customer=customer['id'],
    setup_future_usage='off_session',
    automatic_payment_methods={
      'enabled': True,
    },
  )
```